# Azure Web App Deploy via FTP Credential not Working

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net, microsoft-web-deploy

I have built a web app in ARM (new Portal) with the SDK, and downloaded the Publishing Profile XML file. Inside it has an FTP element with attributes for FTP user name and password. I can log in with those credentials but not upload files - access denied. I cannot delete the hostingstart.html file either. Getting a "dir" on the FTP site works, so I know my credentials are being accepted.

I can see in the Portal GUI that there is an FTP user name, but I do not know its password and it does not match what is in the Publishing Profile XML.

I am trying to provision a brand new web app with the SDK and upload local-built content, completely unattended. How can I make this happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange. Does [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) work on same Web App?

Comment: Which specific SDK nuget package and version that you're using to get the Publish Profile xml? I assume you're using the .NET SDK.

Comment: When you said user name and password, do you mean something like this: userName="<your web app name>\$<your web app name>" userPWD="<a Base-64 string>"?